# How to retrieve the locations of my organization's branches from Google Business Api in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business

I am looking to write JavaScript code for getting the location branches of my organization which is already been verified by google business and using the Business API. Unfortunately I am unable to get any proper implementation in JavaScript to obtain the location in step by step. I will be very thankful if someone can provide the code in JavaScript for the same. I am very new to Google Business API, but read about it in google docs and couldn't find the JavaScript implementation anywhere. I know it requires auth to set up as the data is not public and some samples of its examples are available in docs but its in other languages([here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples)). Please help, thanks in advance.